# How to set autocompletion for only one file ST4?

Tags: sublimetext4

I use Sublime Text 3 (now 4) for my every-day coding. Usually I just open a full folder of my code with different programming languages. In general, everything is ok, but there is a problem with autocompletion. It works for whole project, as a result, I get completions for different languages. Is there a way to set the autocompletion search scope for the parent directory max, or at least only the current file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `"auto_complete_use_index": false,` in your user preferences to keep completions limited to the current file. (Plugins and other completion sources will still be active, but buffer completions from indexed symbols in other files will be disabled.)